# Cut any shape from image ( Imagik/Gd)

Tags: php, image, gd, imagick

Is there any way to cut any shape from square image in PHP ?

Example, I have image with heart shape:

[image]

Another image in same size like heart.

Final image:

[image]

So my question is there way in PHP to make such effect from two images, or one image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically just want to copy the opacity of the heart template into the car picture. So, at the command-line, you would do:

```
convert motor.jpg heart.png -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

And in PHP:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f
<?php
   $template=new Imagick('heart.png');
   $image   =new Imagick('motor.jpg');

   # Copy alpha from template over car image
   $image->compositeImage($template,imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY,0,0);
   $image->writeImage('result.png');
?>
```