# Subtract Png from other Png, preserve transparency, ImageMagick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to Subtract png **mask.png** from **main.png** while maintaining the transparency in **main.png** like this

**main.png**

[image]

**mask.png**

[image]

**mask.png** over **main.png**

[image]

**output.png**

[image]

I found this question on SO [Cut any shape from image ( Imagik/Gd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823319/cut-any-shape-from-image-imagik-gd) but that works well on JPEG image not png as it sets black background.

So far I have come up with this code but yet I cannot get the output as I want

```
exec('convert "main.png" "mask.png" -geometry (+230+40) -compose copyopacity -composite 
-fuzz 1% -trim "output.png"');
```

It gives me output as

[image]

I want that black part to be transparent as it comes from **main.png**

I also tried these but no use

```
exec('convert "main.png" "mask.png" -geometry (+230+40) -fuzz 5% -transparent white 
"output.png"');
```

Here are my [mask.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjSfQ.png) and [main.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmkSQ.png).

[More info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwn6q.png).

This is the code which is finally working by the help of @fmw42

```
 exec('convert "main.png" "mask.png" -background none -geometry (+230+40) -compose dstin -composite -fuzz 1% -trim "output.png"');
```

Comment: It is always impolite to just vote down or closing any question without stating the reason.

Comment: Where is the mask image? Is it the image provided or is it just the blue part?

Comment: @fmw42 That Blue image over Red box is the Mask image. I want to cut that Blue part from main image.

Comment: Please provide both images with actual transparency and not a checkerboard region replacing the transparency.

Comment: Ok please hold on for 5 minutes.

Comment: Is your main image transparent or do you really have a checkerboard there and thus not transparent? Your mask image also has white where I think you want transparency. But I am not sure of either.

Comment: @fmw42 here is the main image https://pasteboard.co/7WugCn6el.png and here is the mask image https://pasteboard.co/7Wv2hfWFD.png

Comment: @fmw42 the checkered box inside Red one is the transparent part of **main.png** and the mask image is like a "T" so, both sides of this T are transparent.

Comment: @fmw42 Have I made you clear? Please look at this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ImageMagick 6.9.8.5 Q16, I get either (depending upon trimming):

```
convert main.png mask.png -background none -gravity center -geometry +0-17 -compose dstin -composite result1.png
```

[image]

```
convert main.png mask.png -background none -gravity center -geometry +0-17 -compose dstin -composite -trim +repage result2.png
```

[image]

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/

Is the above what you want?

NOTE: Your two images are not the same size. The mask is smaller. Thus you need to place it (-geometry) just right to get the result you want.

Comment: May be I wasn't able to make myself clear enough. Please wait so I can test your answer.

Comment: fmw42 your first answer is doing exactly what I wanted but it I don't want that extra space around the image. I just want the **mask.png** part while it is giving output with original. Please check this image https://pasteboard.co/NlFK9UCN.png

Comment: fmw42 I just got the output by triming the white space like this please check if this code is ok or can be make better

Comment: fmw42 please check my updated question. I have pasted the working code over there. Please check if that code is ok or it can be made better

Comment: The only thing I see is that as far as I know -geometry does not require parenthesis about its arguments +X+Y is sufficient. I do not know why you make it (+X+Y). I have never tried it and perhaps it does not matter. You should also add +repage after the -trim. I do not see why in this case you need -fuzz 1%, since the transparency is fully transparent wherever it was used.

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks alot fmw42 that last one comment is really really helpful. Love you man.